# How do I use property defined with Jenkins Pipeline properties step in batch script in the same pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have defined the properties using snippet generator and below is the portion from the jenkinsfile.

```
properties([[$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, rebuildDisabled: false], parameters([string(defaultValue: 'SNAPSHOT', description: '', name: 'BUILD_TYPE'), string(defaultValue: '5.7.0', description: '', name: 'BRANCH_VERSION')]), pipelineTriggers([])])
```

When I echo the above defined properties using either "echo param" or "echo env.param" these parameters are correctly resolved.

Below are resolved correctly:

```
echo BUILD_TYPE
echo BRANCH_VERSION
echo env.BUILD_TYPE
echo env.BRANCH_VERSION
```

However, I need to use these parameters in batch script which is part of the same jenkinsfile, but these parameters are not resolved there. Below is batch portion from the jenkinsfile

```
bat '''echo off
echo "flag:  env.BUILD_TYPE"
echo "flag:  env.BRANCH_VERSION"'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the batch script is a Windows CMD Script, **it must follow syntax for windows CMD.**

ie. This means using correct variable expansion for environmental variables as handled by the CMD Interpreter.

CMD scripts expand the environmental variables by wrapping them in percent signs (or Exclamation Marks `!` when you have Enabled Delayed Expansion).

eg: Jenkins sets Environmental Variable `BUILD_TYPE` CMD Expands this value using `%BUILD_TYPE%` (or `!BUILD_TYPE!` if you use delayed expansion in the cmd script)

**If it was in a stand-alone CMD file it would look like this:**

```
REM Script: Jenkinsbat.cmd
@(SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
)
echo "flag:  %BUILD_TYPE%"
echo "flag:  %BRANCH_VERSION%"
(ENDLOCAL
  Exit /b
)
```

And Jenkins would call it like this by referencing the full path of the script:

```
bat '''REM  Call Script: Jenkinsbat.cmd
ECHO OFF
CALL "\\URL\Share\Path_to_Bat\Jenkinsbat.cmd"'''
```

**Since your batch script is code sitting inside the Jenkins file it should look like this:**

```
bat '''REM Script: Jenkinsbat.cmd
ECHO OFF
echo "flag:  %BUILD_TYPE%"
echo "flag:  %BRANCH_VERSION%"'''
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response Ben.

I use the snippet generator to generate the pipeline script and that is what gives me the output script having three quotes.

I have just pasted a sample script in my question. In actual, the batch section has got lot of commands and they are working fine. The only problem is that the parameters defined outside the batch section in the jenkinsfile are not being resolved inside the batch section.

Comment: My solution still stands.  Just use the one with three single quotes.  (I'll remove the single version. if you are adding these environmental variables to the CMD environment you must use the correct syntax for the CMD interpreter to recall those variables.  CMD scripts expand the environmental variables by wrapping them in percent signs.  So Jenkins variable "BUILD_TYPE" becomes "%BUILD_TYPE%"

Comment: Added clarifying comments to the body of the solution too after removing the question about single versus triple single-quotes (')